# Extending angular class from library injector error

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, extends

This question generally is about extending or replacing components in a component library.  I will use one example of this.  We have a component library we use across projects that contains a number of UI components and directives.  Those components translate themselves on the fly.  The widgets get a translation service injected into them and the programmer specifies keys they want translated.  All good here.

Let's say this base translation service has method getTranslation() to keep it simple.

For most of our products the base translation service works out of the box.  For others, they want to use a different version.  My first thought was define an interface and the base translation / other project's service implements it (normal for Spring Java folks).  I was reading the angular style guide that said 'Consider using a class instead of an interface'.  I dug around a while to understand why (as my background is Java) and it made sense as it seems Angular DI injection works different https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19632.

So, as a test, in a sample project, I created a subclass.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseTranslationService } from './base-translation.service';

@Injectable()
export class MyTranslationService extends BaseTranslationService {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  getTranslation(bundle: string, key: string, params?: any[]): string {

    let translation = super.getTranslation(bundle, key, params);
    return translation + ' from subclass';
  }
}
```

While there are a number of other methods on base translation service, I just wanted to override the one above with some sandbox stuff for this test.

Lastly, in the consuming project, I know longer provide the BaseTranslationService and instead provide the new one:

```
providers: [ MyTranslationService, etc ]
```

This does not work.  I am getting this error on all the components that expect BaseTranslationService:

NullInjectorError: No provider for BaseTranslationService!

It appears then the DI is not understanding MyTranslationService would work for BaseTranslationService.

Should this work?  Did I set it up incorrectly?  Did I misinterpret the style guide?

Comment: did you annotate the `export class MyTranslationService extends BaseTranslationService {` with `@Injectable`? I will post this as answer if it works for you! :) :D

Comment: I think @Aravind is right. You need to decorate MyTranslationService with `@Injectable` and remove `@Injectable` from the BaseTranslationService

Comment: The question lacks http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .. It's unclear where are these classes came from and how they are used. A class that doesn't have deps injected into its constructor doesn't require @Injectable.

Comment: @Aravind I did not have injectable decorator but I do now / updated example above and still same error.   LLai - I cannot remove injectable from BaseTranslationService as in a lot of cases I want to inject it as is.

Comment: @Scott can you add the code for `BaseTranslationService` also. Suggesting you to create a working `plunker` or `stackblitz`

Comment: @Aravind - The next step I had to do is below.  It needed your annotation hint and the answer below.  THANKS for your monitoring and answering my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The components from the library look for a service provided using the token `BaseTranslationService`. But you don't have such a token anymore. You need this instead:

```
providers: [ { provide: BaseTranslationService, useClass: MyTranslationService}, etc ]
```

Update based on comment, you should be annotating the class `MyTranslationService` using the `@Injectable` decorator as below,

```
@Injectable()
export class MyTranslationService extends BaseTranslationService {
...
}
```